# What is `-darwin-21` added to `PLATFORMS` section of my Gemfile.lock file?

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

Recently bundling has added `-darwin-21` to the Gemfile.lock. Now my platforms look like this:

```
PLATFORMS
  -darwin-21
  arm64-darwin
  x86_64-darwin
  x86_64-linux
```

What does `-darwin-21` do/mean, and what might have prompted this change?

Answer (score 1):

It is the platform that libv8-node support

Reference: https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8-node/versions/15.14.0.1-x86_64-darwin-21

x86_64-darwin-21 is the Mac Monterey OS (12.6)